# How to remove negative values from result query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My question is how to remove negative values from query results.My sql query returns both positive and negative values. i want only top 10 positive numbers.But i don't know how to remove negative numbers from result set

Here is my query:

```
SELECT (select account_name from mk_account_master where account_id = atm.account) as account,sum(debit)-sum(credit) as balance,(select Branch_name from mk_branch_master where Branch_id = atm.books) as branch_name from mk_account_transaction_master as atm where account in (SELECT account_id from mk_account_master where type = 'contractor') GROUP BY account,books limit 10
```

Query result :

```
account                     balance      branch_name    
CTA-test@vendor-8761239088  -1320.00    Anthiyur Colony-Erode-Tamil Nadu-1
CTA-test@vendor-8761239088  -1200.00    raj_New@project_Anthiyur_3
CTA-test@vendor-8761239088  -1200.00    raj_Erode_Anthiyur_4
CTA-test@vendor-8761239088  +1500.00    raj_Erode_Anthiyur_5
```

Comment: `WHERE balance >= 0`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_abs.asp

Comment: I already tried this method but sql query raise error " Unknown column 'balance' in 'where clause'"

Comment: sorry. I want remove negative numbers not convert negative to positive

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Balance(field) FROM table WHERE Balance >= 0
```

Comment: Balance - balance. Spelling

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems preety complex. You can make it easy to read and optimized by using JOINS